# Spring boot - mongoDB - compare 2 fields without "$where"

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query

How to compare 2 fields from the same Document - without "$where"

The query worked well - `Criteria.where("$where").is("this.a1 != this.a2")`

but the `--noscripting` parameter was entered,
so I can't use server-side javaScript,
meaning - The solution has got to be without using "$where".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try out something like this:

```
db.source.find({ $expr : { $ne: ["a1", "a2"]  }  })
```

It achieves the same result as your query. Using Spring Data MongoDB Criteria API:

```
Criteria.where("$expr").ne(List.of("a1", "a2"));
```

Comment: thanks for your time, both 2 ways doesn't work.

Comment: @gilln Elaborate please on what do you mean by  "does not work"? What have you done? Please, post your code. It should work.

Comment: this works - `code`Criteria.where("$expr").ne(List.of("$a1", "$a2"))`code`, thanks a lot @Mikhail2048.